# Not able to create data structure for multiple dates to show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I am getting data from microsoft outlook graph api and I am looking for generating recurring data structures. Problem is for some use cases my code completely fails . A example of that recurrence pattern is this

```
{
  recurrence: {
    pattern: {
      type: "weekly",
      interval: 1,
      month: 0,
      dayOfMonth: 0,
      daysOfWeek: ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"],
      firstDayOfWeek: "sunday",
      index: "first",
    },
    range: {
      type: "endDate",
      startDate: "2023-10-26T00:00:00.000Z",
      endDate: "2023-11-10T23:59:00.000Z",
      recurrenceTimeZone: "Romance Standard Time",
      numberOfOccurrences: 0,
    },
  },
}
```

My code is following : -

```
export const generateRecurringDates = (appointment,end_date,start_date) => {
    const { pattern, range } = appointment.recurrence;
    const startDate = new Date(range.startDate);
    let endDate;
    let endTime;
    if(range.type == 'noEnd'){
        endDate = new Date(end_date);
        endTime ='23:59:00.000Z'
    }else{
        endDate = new Date(range.endDate);
        endTime =endDate.toISOString().split('T')[1]
    }
    const recurringDates = [];
    let currentDate = startDate;
    let startTime =currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[1]
    let end;
    if(endDate >=  new Date(end_date)){
        end = new Date(end_date)
    }else{
        end = endDate
    }
    let start;
    let added = true;
    if(startDate >=  new Date(start_date)){
        currentDate = start = startDate
    }else{
        added = false
        currentDate = start = new Date(start_date)
    }
    // currentDate = new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1));
    while (currentDate <= end) {
      // Adjust the date based on the recurrence pattern
      if(pattern?.daysOfWeek?.length > 0){
                pattern?.daysOfWeek?.map((dayName) =>
                {
                    var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
                    if(pattern.type == 'relativeMonthly'){
                        recurringDates.push({
                            start: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                            end: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                            title: appointment.title
                        });
                    }else{
                        if(pattern?.daysOfWeek?.includes(days[currentDate.getDay()].toString()) && currentDate <= end){
                            recurringDates.push({
                                start: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                                end: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                                title: appointment.title
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    currentDate = adjustDate(currentDate, pattern,dayName);
                }
            );
      }else{
            if(currentDate <= end){
                if(pattern.dayOfMonth > 0){
                    if(pattern.month > 0 && (pattern.month == (currentDate.getMonth()+1)) && pattern.dayOfMonth == currentDate.getDate()){
                        recurringDates.push({
                            start: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                            end: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
                        });
                    }else if(pattern.month == 0 && pattern.dayOfMonth == currentDate.getDate()){
                        recurringDates.push({
                            start: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                            end: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
                        });
                    }
                }else{
                    recurringDates.push({
                        start: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                        end: currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]
                    });
                }
            }
            currentDate = adjustDate(currentDate, pattern);
      }
    }
  
    return recurringDates;
  }



 function adjustDate(date, pattern,dayName ='') {
    let newDate = new Date(date);
  
    switch (pattern.type) {
      case "daily":
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + pattern.interval);
        break;
  
      case "weekly":
        // Adjust for the specific day of the week if interval is 1
        if (pattern.interval == 1) {
            let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
            // let day = days.indexOf(dayName.toLowerCase());
            
        }


        if (dayName != '') {
            var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
            var day = days.indexOf(dayName.toLowerCase());
            let addDay = ((day + 7 - newDate.getDay()) % 7);
            if(addDay == 0){
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() +1)
            }else{
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + (((day + 7 - newDate.getDay()) % 7) || 7))
            }
        } else {
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + pattern.interval * 7);
        }
        break;
  
      case "absoluteMonthly":
        // Adjust for the specific day of the month
        if (pattern.dayOfMonth) {
          const currentMonth = newDate.getMonth();
          const targetDayOfMonth = pattern.dayOfMonth;
  
          if (targetDayOfMonth > newDate.getDate()) {
            newDate.setDate(targetDayOfMonth);
          } else {
            // Move to the next month
            newDate.setMonth(currentMonth + 1);
            newDate.setDate(targetDayOfMonth);
          }
        } else {
          newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + pattern.interval);
        }
        break;
    
    // case "relativeMonthly":
    //     // Adjust for the specific day of the week
    //     if (pattern.daysOfWeek && pattern.daysOfWeek.length > 0) {
    //         const dayName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { weekday: 'long' }).format(newDate).toLowerCase();
    //         const targetDayIndex = pattern.daysOfWeek.indexOf(dayName);
    //         console.log(targetDayIndex)
    //         if (targetDayIndex >= 0) {
    //           let daysToAdd = getNthDayOfMonth(newDate, pattern.index, pattern.daysOfWeek);
    //           console.log(daysToAdd,'daysToAdd')
    //           if (daysToAdd === 0) {
    //             // If daysToAdd is zero, move to the next occurrence in the next month
    //             newDate.setDate(1);
    //             newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + pattern.interval);
    //             daysToAdd = getNthDayOfMonth(newDate, pattern.index, pattern.daysOfWeek);
    //           }
    
    //           newDate.setDate(daysToAdd);
    //         } else {
    //             newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() +1)
    //         }
    //     } else {
    //         newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + pattern.interval);
    //     }
    //     break;
        
    case "relativeMonthly":
        if (pattern.daysOfWeek && pattern.daysOfWeek.length > 0) {
            var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
            var day = days.indexOf(dayName.toLowerCase());
            var nextOccurrence = findNthDayOfMonth(newDate.getFullYear(), newDate.getMonth(), day, pattern.index);
            newDate = new Date(nextOccurrence);
        } else {
            newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + pattern.interval);
        }
        break;


      case "absoluteYearly":
        // Adjust for the specific day of the month
        if (pattern.dayOfMonth > 0) {
            const targetDate = new Date(newDate);
            targetDate.setMonth(pattern.month - 1);
            targetDate.setDate(pattern.dayOfMonth);
    
            if (targetDate <= newDate) {
              newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + pattern.interval);
              newDate.setMonth(pattern.month - 1);
              newDate.setDate(pattern.dayOfMonth);
            } else {
              newDate.setMonth(pattern.month - 1);
              newDate.setDate(pattern.dayOfMonth);
            }
          } else {
            newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + pattern.interval);
            newDate.setMonth(pattern.month - 1);
            newDate.setDate(1);
    
            while (newDate.getDay() !== 0) {
              newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            }
    
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + (pattern.interval - 1) * 7);
          }
        break;
  
    //   case "relativeYearly":
    //     // Adjust for the specific day of the week
    //     if (pattern.daysOfWeek && pattern.daysOfWeek.length > 0) {
            
    //         if (dayName != '') {
    //             newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + pattern.interval);
    //             newDate.setMonth(pattern.month - 1);
    //             var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
    //             var day = days.indexOf(dayName.toLowerCase());
    //             newDate.setDate(1); // Set to the first day of the month
    //             while (newDate.getDay() !== day) {
    //                 // Move to the next day until it's a Friday
    //                 newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    //             }
    //         }
    //     } else {
    //       newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + pattern.interval);
    //     }
    //     break;
          
    case "relativeYearly":
        if (pattern.daysOfWeek && pattern.daysOfWeek.length > 0) {
            var days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
            var day = days.indexOf(dayName.toLowerCase());
            var nextOccurrence = findNthDayOfMonth(newDate.getFullYear() + pattern.interval, pattern.month - 1, day, pattern.index);
            newDate = new Date(nextOccurrence);
        } else {
            newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + pattern.interval);
        }
        break;
    

      // Add more cases for other recurrence types if needed
  
      default:
        break;
    }
  
    return newDate;
  }
```

this is constantly failing to get me code where recurrence pattern is above. Where am I making mistake in my logic.

Comment: What's actually missing is the target data-structure. I can't imaging anyone willing to go through the 238 lines of your posted script without a clue about the expected result.

Comment: My apologies I will post the expected result soon. i will edit the question soon.